# Liferay 7 - Allow svg image upload (Set as valid extension)

Tags: svg, liferay, portal, liferay-7

I just tried to upload an svg image to my Liferay portal, and the following error message appeared:

> "Invalid file extension"

**So my Question:**
Where can I set .svg as a valid image extension ??

I tried to add this to portal-ext.properties

```
dl.file.extensions=*
```

Still not working..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**Liferay 7.2 solution**

Control Panel -> System Setting -> Documents and Media -> Service -> add .svg

Control Panel -> System Setting -> Documents and Media -> Item Selector View -> add .svg

Answer (score 0):

So found the soloution: Server administration -> file upload -> web content file extensions